# Android Audio Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

General question about playing audio from my android app through bluetooth device:

If I have my device paired with the bluetooth device, when I play the mp3 file from the app I am developing, will it automatically route to the bluetooth device?

If not can someone point in the direction of a tutorial on this subject?

Comment: If it's paired _and_ connected as a media device, then yes, I would expect music playback to be routed to the BT device. This sort of implies that you're using an A2DP-capable BT accessory; music will not be routed to a basic BT handsfree except in special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any sample code?  Or are you just brainstorming at this point?

With the correct permissions and calls, yes, it'll play through whatever the Android system determines as the primary **media** audio output.

Reference from Google on android.media: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies @Michael and IAmTheSquidward. Yes I have followed the Android tutorial for scanning for and pairing devices. I was intending to just play the audio file with MediaPlayer, just wanted to ask was it as simple as that  or if I was over thinking things

Comment: Nope, you're on track.  Just pass it through MediaPlayer.

Comment: If you are searching for a test app for Audio routing here's one which might help you at my Github: https://github.com/sauravpradhan/Basic-Audio-Routing